# David Hume - Reason being a slave the passions

Tags: hume, reason

In David Humes' book, "A Treatise of Human Nature" he states that reason is the slave to the passions.

"*Reason is, and ought only to be the slave of the passions, and can never pretend to any other office than to serve and obey them*. (T 2.3.3 p. 415)"

Could someone explain this to me, preferably reconstructing in a premise-conclusion format.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can see [A Treatise of Human Nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Treatise_of_Human_Nature#Sections_3.E2.80.938) for a detialed commentary.

Answer (score 1):

*I want an ice-cream
The ice-cream shop is open now
Therefore I shall go and get an ice-cream*

This does not work without the passionate 'wanting' of ice-cream. Many (but perhaps not all) bits of human reasoning are 'passion driven' in this way. I am grateful to [my first year ethics lecturer](http://www.bbk.ac.uk/philosophy/our-staff/academic_staff/dr-cristian-constantinescu) for this explanation. If there's an error it's mine, not his.